Width of the quick settings menu way too large
The quick settings are comically large for no reason. I've tried rebooting and disabling extensions, but the issue still persists after a restart.


GPU: NVidia 3060 - proprietary drivers 550.78
Monitor: 3440x1440 GB3461WQSU
Fedora workstation 40
gnome 43


Thank you for the information, but without some information about your system, in particular resolution and graphics card, there is little that can be said. Most users do not have this issue.

Thank you for the comment, but without some information about possible steps to take, in particular common steps to take to resolvethis issue, there is little that can I can add. Most users indeed do not have this issue, thus me creating this thread.

You're asking at the wrong place, we support only Ubuntu and it's official flavours but for sure not Fedora.

Indeed, such issues may be specific to a distribution. This forum adopted the policy to focus on Ubuntu and flavors (Xubuntu, Kubuntu, …) only.

Next time I'll ask on askgnome.com !My bad for thinking the biggest distro using exclusively this desktop-manager might help me with this issue
